# Service Fabric Reliable Collections - Are key filters applied in deterministic order for CreateEnumerableAsync?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm attempting to implement cursor-based pagination for a reliable dictionary. I know that `IReliableDictionary` keys must implement `IComparable`, and that `IReliableDictionary` this method for enumerating dictionary entries:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>> 
CreateEnumerableAsync (
    ITransaction txn, 
    Func<TKey,bool> filter,
    EnumerationMode enumerationMode);
```

When `EnumerationMode.Ordered` is used, I assume we enumerate the key-value pairs according to the key's `IComparable` implementation.

Can we also assume the `filter` parameter is applied to each key in order of the key's `IComparable` implementation? Maybe another way to ask - are keys laid out in memory and/or enumerated in order of their `IComparable` implementation? If so, is this behavior documented, or should it be considered an implementation detail that may change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed an experiment using the [Voting Web](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-quickstart) sample, and the keys do appear to be filtered in order of their `IComparable` implementation, with some caveats:

- It appears the filter can be run multiple times over the same key
- The filter can be applied to items which have been recently deleted

`VotingData.Controllers.VoteDataController` has the following get and put operations to list and add voting categories:

```
[HttpPut("{name}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(string name)
{
    IReliableDictionary<string, int> votesDictionary = await this.stateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, int>>("counts");

    using (ITransaction tx = this.stateManager.CreateTransaction())
    {
        await votesDictionary.AddOrUpdateAsync(tx, name, 1, (key, oldvalue) => oldvalue + 1);
        await tx.CommitAsync();
    }

    return new OkResult();
}
```

I modified `Get` to enumerate `votesDictionary` in order, and applied a filter which builds a list of keys seen by the filter:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
     CancellationToken ct = new CancellationToken();
     IReliableDictionary<string, int> votesDictionary = await this.stateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, int>>("counts");            

     var filteredKeys = new List<string>();

     using (ITransaction tx = this.stateManager.CreateTransaction())
     {
        IAsyncEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> list = await votesDictionary.CreateEnumerableAsync(tx,                                                                                                        key =>
                                                                                                     {
                                                                                                           lock (this.locker)
                                                                                                           {
                                                                                                               filteredKeys.Add(key);
                                                                                                               return true;
                                                                                                           }
                                                                                                       },
                                                                                                       EnumerationMode.Ordered);
        IAsyncEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, int>> enumerator = list.GetAsyncEnumerator();
        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

        while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync(ct))
        {
            result.Add(enumerator.Current);
        }
         return this.Json(result);
    }
}
```

I added keys to the dictionary in random alphabetical order and refreshed the page to run the `Get` query. On each refresh, the `filteredKeys` collection contained my entries in sorted alphabetical order. As mentioned above, the collection sometimes contained duplicate entries for certain strings. When I removed items from the collection and refreshed the page, I found deleted keys were still added to `filteredKeys`, although these elements were not returned in the result enumeration.

Comment: Not thrilled about accepting my own answer in this case - would like to have seen something more authoritative. Nevertheless, the experiment shows that although filters are applied in key order, it can't be relied upon to precisely enumerate the current set of keys (no deleted keys, each key processed once).